# Install libraries into MSYS2 from source

Tags: opencv, mingw-w64, msys2

I have installed MSYS2 along with mingw64 on windows.

How do I install an application or library (in this case OpenCV) from the source code into mingw64 in the same way as pacman does, ideally using the CMAKE-GUI (due to a number of options to set)?

I have tried using

1. Use CMake-Gui to generate a mingw-makefile, with an additional DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH entry.
2. Running mingw64 make installed
3. The code compiles fine but then installing into the CMAKe build directory4
4. MSYS pkg-manager can not see the library (opencv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pacman` for MSYS2 is an MSYS2 port of the ArchLinux package manager,
[pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman).

To make an application or library installable "in the same way as pacman",
and so that `pacman` can see it, you need to make a `pacman` package
of it: here is [the documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/creating_packages)